# Override or remove an object from __init__ parent class from child's class

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently, I have two classes:

```
 class Parent:
    def __init__(self, controller, parent):
        # Key press event bind 'Return Key'
        self.controller.bind('<Return>', self.averageTesting)

    def averageTesting(variable):
        if len(variable) > 0:
           return variable
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Enter a valid variable") 

 class Child(Parent):
      def __init__(self):
          ......
```

The parent class is actually page one and child class is page two of the Tkinter frame pages.

I don't want the child to have the messagebox showing. Right now when I go to page two or the child class and I press return on my keyboard, the message shows up. And I don't want that in the second page. Only the first page which is the parent class.

But I need to inherit everything but the messagebox from the parent class to the child class.

How do I do achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think that if you must exclude parts of your parent's constructor then your design is flawed. You could instead make the parent class more generic and make your current parent and your current child both inherit from the new parent.

If you really want to stick with that pattern then you could just unbind the event. If this is the only callback connected to the event then you can just do.

```
x = Child() 
x.controller.unbind('<Return>')
```

Edit:

My next suggestion is to instead move the binding to a separate method inside the parent class. For example.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, controller, parent):
        self.controller = controller
        ...

    def averageTesting(variable):
        if len(variable) > 0:
            return variable
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Enter a valid variable") 


    def initializeBinding(self):
        self.controller.bind('<Return>', self.averageTesting)
        ... # plus anymore bindings that only the parent must have

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
      ...
```

So now when you want to use the parent you would do this.

```
p = Parent(...)
p.initializeBinding()
```

Whereas when you instantiate a Child object you don't call the method.

Comment: I tried to unbind in my child and parent classes but it didn't work.

Comment: Another suggestion, that would be better than trying to unbind would be to make some sort of initialisation method to call the event binding from. This way your child class will not be bound unless you choose to call the function that binds it.

Comment: What do you mean by initialization method? Can you give me an example?     I also tried creating a global bind and unbind method... but when I did that... well... the child still got the parent's